# Convert nngraph model to nn model

Tags: caffe, torch, pytorch, caffe2

I want to convert the pix2pix Image to Image translation model (https://github.com/phillipi/pix2pix) which is built using nngraph.

When I try to convert it to caffe model using torch to caffe tool (https://github.com/facebook/fb-caffe-exts#torch2caffe) I get the error "unknown class nn.gModule".

I also try to load torch model in pytorch by load_lua from torch.utils.serialization where I get similar error.

Since, it seems nngraph is not supported for conversion. Is there a way to convert nngraph model to nn model without the need of rewriting or retraining? Down the line, I want to convert the pix2pix model into various formats like caffe, caffe2, coreML and others to test the performance in mobile environment.

Thanks